# JQuery: trying to use .html() but the new content takes on link characteristics of the original selector/element

Tags: jquery

I have four links and I would like content to appear in a div(.contentcont [name of div]) below the list of links for that particular link that was clicked.

```
$('.link1').click(function(e){
$(this).clone().html('<h1>Text appear</h1>')
.appendTo('.contentcont')
               e.preventDefault();  
       });
```

I am using .html() to provide the content to be entered into the div. If you take a look at the js fiddle provided( http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/K3FaY/2/) you will be able to see that the new content is appearing in the div but it's taking on the characteristic of the link [no good]. Maybe it has to do with me using .clone(). The reason why I am using .clone() is because when ever I clicked on the link the link would disappear. maybe you can tell me if using .clone() was the right solution to use to prevent the link from disappearing. And why the new content is taking on the link characteristic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html()` sets the *inner* HTML of your element. Your cloned element is still a `<a>` tag (you cloned your link), so you're essentially appending a copy of your link with different text into the other element.

If I'm reading your code correctly, you really don't need to use `.clone()` or `.html()` at all. Just create a new element:

```
$('<h1 />', {
    text: 'Text appear'
}).appendTo('.contentcont');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/K3FaY/8/**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It gave me some ideas that I could use for the future. It's just that I would like to style the text too and I would not know how to  do that just by  using the 'text:' thing. that's why I was trying to use .html() so I could create some styling with the html. but I see from SidMS answer I could do that with the knowledge that I have now of Jquery (I am new at this). Again thank you for taking the time to provide your answer to me. It was helpful.

Comment: The `text` thing is just a shorthand for `.text()`. Using `html` in place of `text` will do exactly what you think it will do. You can add other attributes into the object as well, like `id`, `name`, etc, but you're probably looking for `class`: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/K3FaY/12/

Answer (score 2):

The new content is taking on the link characteristic because you are cloning the link element itself. For adding new content simply use:

```
$('.contentcont').append('<h1>Text appear</h1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the cloned link to a temporary parent node, like a div, and then pulling the html back out using `innerHTML` or `$.html()`

Answer (score 0):

The new content is taking on the characteristic of the link because it is added directly as child in the `<a>...</a>` element, cause of `clone()`.
Try add the new content in the Div, using its ID , and without using clone().